# Sencha Touch 2: Facebook JS SDK not working on device, only in computer-browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, extjs, sdk, sencha-touch

I'm developing a Sencha Touch 2 app that uses the Facebook JavaScript SDK to show a Facebook feed in a list. In my browser (localhost) it works perfect, but when I launch my app on my device (iPhone of iPad), the feed does not load. Neither when I open it via localhost in Safari on the devices.

When I use the Safari-console on my iPhone, it shows two logs which don't appear on my computer:

"JavaScript logfile at line 44: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js: Received message of type object from https://s-static.ak.facebook.com, expected a string"

Is this causing the problem? Maybe the FB-functions of the Javascript SDK don't get recognized on my device?

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some example code? Alternatively, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675944/facebook-ios-mobile-web-js-sdk-error).

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining the script of fb and where is the div fb-root the defined I had the same problem before but it was because the div was always override or overwrited by another view, so check that if you can post some of the code would be better,

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the fb domains added to the app url whitelist? I have had similar problem and it was solved by adding the fb domains to the access origin tag of the config file.