# Facebook iOS Mobile Web JS SDK Error

Tags: ios, facebook-javascript-sdk

We already have Facebook working on our main desktop app without an issue. When I added the same setup code to our mobile site I received an error from the JavaScript SDK:

`Received message of type object from https://s-static.ak.facebook.com, expected a string`

Then, I changed the setup code to an exact replica from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/ and received the exact same message.

This error only shows when the user-agent is iOS or Android in Chrome Developer Tools or in the iOS Simulator. When it's running from the desktop, we aren't seeing this error.

Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error. This isn't necessarily the reason you're getting it, but I ended up looking at the packets being received by my iphone simulator, and here's the error from s-statick.ak:

```
[truncated] <span>Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App&#039;s settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one o
```

For me, the error is that on my device(s), I'm accessing the site through an ip address (192.168.xx etc) and on local development I have hosts routing localhost to a url that is in my facebook app config... so the IP isn't configured for the app.

Facebook won't let me use an IP address, so it seems like the only option is a test deploy or a DNS server. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and something I should have considered. Thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 5):

With all due respect, I believe that bokonic's answer is missing the point. The immediate reason of the message you're receiving is most likely javascript `postMessage` method. It is used to communicate your website with an object returned by `window.open` or an `iframe`'s embedded website.

```
window.parent.postMessage(message, targetOrigin);
```

You might want to have a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585663/Communication-with-Cross-Domain-IFrame-A-Cross-Bro) to see how it works.

According to [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) first argument of the `postMessage` method can be of any type. Still, *Prior to Gecko 6.0 (Firefox 6.0 / Thunderbird 6.0 / SeaMonkey 2.3), the message parameter **must be a string**.*

I tested the method on Chrome 28.0.1500.72 (latest version when writing this answer) and it works fine when passing an object but still throws the warning message to the console. I believe that facebook feels uncomfortable with passing some rich data as a string so they pass it as an object and simply doesn't care about the warning. Or, since there is a workaround (e.g. `JSON.stringify`), they have a bug they don't know about.

Comment: seems correct but actually the warning message is coming from within the facebook sdk ITSELF—its not a part of the browser or anything, its part of the facebook sdk. (this can trivially be confirmed by a breakpoint on the source of the console output) this is really annoying if your app happens to use postMessage for anything, because facebook will happily spam the console with a million "warning" messages for a bounty of events not intended for it.

Comment: I think this is more correct answer. The warning happening because of the window.postMessage method.I ended up here with same warning, but not because of emulator. I used an extra postMessage and FB sdk is listening for the message too & throwing error since I was sending an object!