# Facebook SDK - warnings in console "Received message of type number from http://localhost:8080, expected a string"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using latest version of Facebook JS SDK - http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js but it populates my dev console with numerous warnings: `Received message of type number from http://localhost:8080, expected a string`. I cannot understand what is the cause..

That's how I'm initializing sdk on html page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 1234567890, // my app id here
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.3'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, those are _warnings_ only, so this should not be a thing that keeps your app from working. Secondly, they might(!) just be caused by your local test setup – using a different port than the default 80 can have some side effects when dealing with the JS SDK.

Comment: I have also seen this happen in Chrome, when browser extensions communicate with their injected content script using messaging. As said before, these are just warnings. Check again in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

see this:
[Facebook iOS Mobile Web JS SDK Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675944/facebook-ios-mobile-web-js-sdk-error)

are you using Babel?
if so I have the same problem:
https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2198